# plink command to get .txt output on local commandline

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

On a linux server I have a file called "versions.txt"
I would like that output on my local screen (with bash file, I already created that) and then proceed with my bash file.

Annyone has a sugestion how to do this? I already tried alot of different methods in 1 command.

Last I tried was:

```
start C:\tools\PLINK.EXE -ssh -pw <password> -t <user>@10.111.11.111 "ls -l" > /var/www/html/test/SM/SCRIPT/versions.txt"
```

But that doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the remote file `/var/www/html/test/SM/SCRIPT/versions.txt` exists on the 10.111.11.111 machine, this command will output the file to your local [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)):

```
C:\tools\PLINK.EXE -ssh -pw <password> -t <user>@10.111.11.111 "cat /var/www/html/test/SM/SCRIPT/versions.txt"
```

I also remove `start`, because it starts another shell.

Comment: Indeed this works! hmm strange I couldnt manage that. thanks alot!